# C# Reflection Check for Implemented Interface UWP

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp

So i try to create a PluginService which loads assemblys from a folder and checks if it implements a certain interface. I work with the Interface

```
public interface IService
    {
        void Start();
        void Stop();
        void Restart();
    }
```

And the Class

```
public class Service : IService
    {

        public Service()
        {

        }

        public void Restart()
        {

        }

        public void Start()
        {

        }

        public void Stop()
        {

        }
    }
```

And i found [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941065/finding-objects-that-implement-interface-from-loaded-assembly-how-to-compare-ty) from pogorman which helped me a lot. 
**EDIT:**
Sorry for the confussion i mean this code snippet not the `DoesTypeImplementInterface`

```
currentAssembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t != typeof(T) && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => implementors.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(x)));
```

Comment: Can you please add the code, where you use the method?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you sure, you have an assembly with this Interface implemented?

Comment: @MartinZikmund The code returns no Class but there is one Class that implements the IService Interface.

Comment: @Nikolaus yeah if i debug it the `TypeInfo.ImplementedInterfaces` Property of the Class Service is `IService`

Comment: I‘ll do further research, because I had a similar issue.

Comment: Try:` t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (T))` instead of the IsAssignableFrom-part. Does it work then?

Comment: Is it possible, that you work with .net Core?

Comment: My suspicion is that the `IService` that's being implemented by the services is not the same one (doesn't have the same runtime identity) as the one that the host is trying to check. As a test, get the `IService` type instance from the type you know implements it and check that it's reference-equal to `typeof(IService)` in the host. If not, look at the types' `Assembly` properties. Chances are that they're different types in the same namespace, compiled into both host and plugin assemblies.

Comment: @Nikolaus Unfortunately not :\

Comment: Then I think madreflections comment looks quite realistic.